# source port number in the recvfrom socket function

Tags: c, sockets

I'm wondering on what basis `src_addr.sin_port` while receiving socket data gets filled up in the last but one argument of `recvfrom` function, syntax of which is

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

ssize_t recvfrom(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
                 struct sockaddr *src_addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

And also what's the significance of it, does it help the receiver in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP and port that is populated after a successful call to `recvfrom` is the source IP and port of the received datagram.  This can be logged so the user knows where the datagram came from.

Also, if a datagram needs to be sent back to this endpoint, `src_addr` can be passed to `sendto` to specify the destination IP and port.

Comment: But I think there is no way we can specify the port number while sending the data using `sendto` function, synatx of which is `ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,
               const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);`. Does this mean it gets filled by sender OS?

Comment: @Harry The destination port number would be contained in `dest_addr->sin_port`.

Comment: Correct, then how the sender's port number gets filled up when data gets received using `recvfrom` function? Also, what's the guarantee that the other endpoint will be listening on that same port?

Comment: @Harry After a call from `recvfrom`, the `sin_port` field contains the port number of the remote side.  That port number (along with the IP) can then be used to send a response back to that IP and port.  Also, UDP sockets doesn't "listen" in the same sense that TCP sockets do.  The socket on the other side would be able to call `recvfrom` to get the response.

Comment: @Harry A UDP socket can call `bind` to bind to a specific port.  If that is not done, the OS will select a port number after the first send or receive.